# web3.eth.sign vs web3.eth.signTransaction, different or the same?

Tags: web3js

Does web3.eth.sign do the same thing as web3.eth.signTransaction?
For instance, could I sign a transaction with web3.eth.sign?

What is happening under the hood with those two methods?

Comment: As per my knowledge, web3 uses this library  for signing for both after doing some processing on data : https://www.npmjs.com/package/secp256k1

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md this can also help you to understand parameter processing